# Send money to someone with Bank of America

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer, online

My nanny has a Bank of America account.  What is the easiest way to send her money electronically.  She is not tech savvy.

I've tried Quick Pay multiple times, she can't seem to figure it out.  I then bill payed her checks to her bank but BofA started charging a fee for that.  Is popmoney easier?  Or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What about good old fashioned personal checks?

Comment: Charging for billpay? That seems silly.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the fee is for and what bank you are using? Bank of America does not charge fees to use bill pay to pay someone. See their FAQ: https://www.bankofamerica.com/onlinebanking/ebills-faqs.go

Comment: The problem with personal checks is I have over 50 accounts to service so I'm trying to automate as much as possible.  I have a Chase account.  My nanny said BofA was charging her a fee to open the piece of mail, take the physical check out that I sent via Chase Bill Pay, and deposit it in her account.

Comment: @auby1885 Can you have your bill pay service send the check to your nanny ' s address rather than the bank? I do this with my rent check to my landlord, but I'm a BoA customer..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of solutions I would use starting with the easiest:

1. Check to see if your bank offers the ability to send money to someone's bank account by entering the recipient's checking account number and bank's routing number. If so get the recipient's account info from a voided check. USAA and Capital One 360 offer this feature and other may as well for free. Bank of America also offers this service but charge $3 per payment.
2. Check to see if your bank has the ability to pay someone by text or email. This will require the recipient to enter their own account information on your bank's system 1 time, but after that payments should be deposited into the recipient's account automatically. This is almost as easy as the first option. Bank of America does not charge for this option.
3. Use PopMoney, a third party service, to complete the payment like in option 1. This is almost as convenient as option 1 but requires a 3rd party service.
4. Use your bank's bill pay to mail a check as others have suggested.